# i want to insert refferal_code value in users table with laravel register api

Tags: php, laravel

register function look like this..
this function works but refferal_code not inserting
i'm sending values with postman 
first_name, last_name, email, phone, password, c_password, refferal_code

```
public function register(Request $request, User $user) 
{ 
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'first_name' => 'required', 
        'last_name' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users', 
        'phone' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required', 
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) { 
        return response()->json(['result'=>'false','error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);          
    }
    else{
        $data = $request->all();
        $chars = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $res = $chars[mt_rand(10, strlen($chars)-1)].rand().$chars[mt_rand(10, strlen($chars)-1)];
        $data['refferal_code'] = $res;
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        //print_r($data);exit;
        $user->create($data);

        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        $success['first_name'] =  $user->first_name;
        return response()->json(['result'=>'true', 'success'=>'User created.'], $this-> successStatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your model doesn't have **refferal_code** in his `$fillable` array. Can you check it ?

If you don't want to have problems with this, try using it in your User model

```
protected $fillable = [];
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'image', 'password', 'status', 'city_id', 'state_id',
    ];

Comment: Is it what you have in your model ? Or you changed it and it's working now ?